# is there an easy way to binarize this ecg sample image?

Tags: python, image, opencv

iam a beginner at python and opencv. Iam interested about image processing and iam about to binarize this image.

[This is the image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKNKt.png)

[The final processed image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6La9.png)

this is what i try and the step that i implemented. Iam reading about image segmenting and grid removing. The thing that i understand is:

1. grayscaling image
2. blur the image
3. binarize the image
4. morphological operation

Here's the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#load an image
img = cv2.imread('src.png')
#grayscaling image
gray0 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#blur image-1
blurred0 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray0, (3,3), 0)
#thresholding an image-1
t, thresh4 = cv2.threshold(blurred0, 158, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

#creating kernel
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
#morphological operations
opening1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh4, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
#repeat blur-2
close = cv2.GaussianBlur(opening1, (3,3), 0)
#repeat thresholding-2
t, threshz = cv2.threshold(close, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#repeat blur-3
layer0 = cv2.GaussianBlur(threshz, (5,5), 0)
#repeat thresholding-3
t, threshz = cv2.threshold(layer0, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#morph close
threshzx = cv2.morphologyEx(threshz, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

i felt there's simple way than repeating this code to obtain the binarized image that we want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could try thinning your result to the medial line (center line) to improve it.  Otherwise, I know of no other way to remove your background other than AI/Deep Learning with training, unless you have a clean grid image with no signal. Then you could register (align) the two grids and subtract the aligned clean grid from your image.

Comment: okai, so if i learn about deep learning it will be worth it? and where i should start deep learning... is convolutional network enough?

Comment: I tried your image on http://remove.bg and it did not work. So general AI does not seem to work. I would suggest that you explore doing background subtraction after registration if you have a clean grid image that matches your image.

Comment: i dont understand :(, registration what? :"

Comment: Registration is the process of aligning two images. In your case it would be your image with signal and your grid image with no signal. One generally picks corresponding points on each and then from that finds a homography matrix that then is used to warp one image to match the other.